# Error setting a default null value for an annotation's field

Tags: java, annotations, default

Why am I getting an error "Attribute value must be constant". Isn't **null** constant???

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeInterface {
    Class<? extends Foo> bar() default null;// this doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: Because as there is no default anymore, the field becomes mandatory in annotation usage

Comment: It’s funny that no-one answered the question: “Isn’t `null` constant?” The answer is no, in Java, `null` is not a constant. `null` can not be used at any place where a compile-time constant is required. E.g. try to add `String foo() default "" + null;` to your annotation. We know, the expression predictably evaluates to `"null"`, still, it’s not a constant expression, hence, not allowed.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I don't know why, but the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html) is very clear:

```
 Discussion

 Note that null is not a legal element value for any element type.
```

And the definition of a default element is:

```
     DefaultValue:
         default ElementValue
```

Unfortunately I keep finding that the new language features (Enums and now Annotations) have very unhelpful compiler error messages when you don't meet the language spec.

EDIT: A little googleing found the [following](https://web.archive.org/web/20090804142546/http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.html#htoc48) in the JSR-308, where they argue for allowing nulls in this situation:

> We note some possible objections to the proposal.
>
> The proposal doesn't make anything possible that was not possible before.
>
> The programmer-defined special value provides better documentation than null, which might mean “none”, “uninitialized”, null itself, etc.
>
> The proposal is more error-prone. It's much easier to forget checking against null than to forget checking for an explicit value.
>
> The proposal may make the standard idiom more verbose. Currently only the users of an annotation need to check for its special values. With the proposal, many tools that process annotations will have to check whether a field's value is null lest they throw a null pointer exception.

I think only the last two points are relevant to "why not do it in the first place." The last point certainly brings up a good point - an annotation processor never has to be concerned that they will get a null on an annotation value. I tend to see that as more the job of annotation processors and other such framework code to have to do that kind of check to make the developers code clearer rather than the other way around, but it would certainly make it hard to justify changing it.

Answer (score 73):

Try this

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeInterface {
    Class bar() default void.class;
}
```

It does not require a new class and it is already a keyword in Java that means nothing.

Comment: I like it. The only problem – in the context of the original question – is that this answer does not support type parameters:

    `Class<? extends Foo> bar() default void.null`

does not compile.

Comment: The void.class can't be applied generally: public @interface NoNullDefault { String value() default void.class; }

Comment: For Groovy it works fine, even in the cases mentioned in the comments

Comment: *LOL:* that means nothing *vs* that means "nothing"

Answer (score 55):

It would seem this is illegal, although the JLS is very fuzzy on this.

I wracked my memory to try and think of an existing annotation out there that had a Class attribute to an annotation, and remembered this one from the JAXB API:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({PACKAGE,FIELD,METHOD,TYPE,PARAMETER})        
public @interface XmlJavaTypeAdapter {
    Class type() default DEFAULT.class;

    static final class DEFAULT {}    
}
```

You can see how they've had to define a dummy static class to hold the equivalent of a null.

Unpleasant.

Comment: Yes, we do something similar (we just use Foo.class as the default). Sucks.

Comment: And in the case of String fields, you have to resort to [magic strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string). Apparently well-known antipatterns are better than well-understood language features now.

Comment: @TimYates  It kills me to see people defining their own "no value" sentinel value when null is available and universally understood.   And now that's being required by the language itself?!  Luckily, you can define your "magic strings" as public constants.  It's still not ideal but at least the code that's looking for your annotation can reference the constant instead of using literals everywhere.

Answer (score 13):

It seem there is one other way of doing it.

I don't like this either, but it might work.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeInterface {
    Class<? extends Foo>[] bar() default {};
}
```

So basically you create an empty Array instead. This seems to allow a default value.

Comment: I saw this approach being used by picocli.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Class<? extends Foo> bar() default null;// this doesn't compile
> ```

As mentioned, the Java language specification does not allow null values in the annotations defaults.

What I tend to do is to do is to define `DEFAULT_VALUE` constants at the top of the annotation definition.  Something like:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public static final String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "__class-name-here__ default";
    ...
    public String prefix() default DEFAULT_PREFIX;
}
```

Then in my code I do something like:

```
if (myAnnotation.prefix().equals(MyAnnotation.DEFAULT_PREFIX)) { ... }
```

In your case with a class, I would just define a marker class.  Unfortunately you can't have a constant for this so instead you need to do something like:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public static Class<? extends Foo> DEFAULT_BAR = DefaultBar.class;
    ...
    Class<? extends Foo> bar() default DEFAULT_BAR;
}
```

Your `DefaultFoo` class would just an empty implementation so that the code can do:

```
if (myAnnotation.bar() == MyAnnotation.DEFAULT_BAR) { ... }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Incidentally, I just tried this with a String, and that doesn't work.  You don't get back the same String object.

Comment: Did you use `.equals()` and not `==` @Doradus?  Did you get a different _value_ or a different object.

Comment: Different object.  I used `==`.

Comment: Well the class is a singleton @Doradus.  I would have expected the String to be a singleton as well but I guess it isn't and you'll need to use `.equals()`.  Surprising.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is a rule which says that null is not a valid default value in Java.

**If you've got a limited number of possible values that the field can have**, then one option for working around this is to make the field type a custom enum which itself contains a mapping to null. For example, imagine I have the following annotation that I want a default null for:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   Class<?> value() default null;
}
```

As we've established, this is not allowed. What we can instead do is define an enum:

```
public enum MyClassEnum {
    NULL(null),
    MY_CLASS1(MyClass1.class),
    MY_CLASS2(MyClass2.class),
    ;

    public final Class<?> myClass;

    MyClassEnum(Class<?> aClass) {
        myClass = aClass;
    }
}
```

and change the annotation as such:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  MyClassEnum value() default MyClassEnum.NULL;
}
```

The main downside of this (asides from needing to enumerate your possible values) is that you've now wrapped your value in an enum, so you'll need to invoke the property/getter on the enum to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

No, the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) does not define the `null` literal/value as a constant expression.

The [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.2) states the following when defining the possible default values for annotation type elements:

> It is a compile-time error if the type of the element **is not commensurate** (§9.7) with the default value specified.

And to [explain what that means](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1)

> It is a compile-time error if the element type is not commensurate
> with the element value. **An element type T is commensurate with an
> element value V** if and only if one of the following is true:
>
> - `T` is an array type `E[]`, and either:
> - [...]
> - **`T` is not an array type**, and the type of `V` is assignment compatible (§5.2) with `T`, **and**:
> - If `T` is a primitive type or `String`, then `V` is a constant expression (§15.28).
> - If `T` is `Class` or an invocation of `Class` (§4.5), then `V` is a class literal (§15.8.2).
> - If `T` is an enum type (§8.9), then `V` is an enum constant (§8.9.1).
> - **V is not null**.

So here, your element type, `Class<? extends Foo>`, is not commensurate with the default value, because that value is `null`.