# Annotation default "null" value

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to specify a annotation with a null as default?

What I want to achieve is something like optional annotation attributes.

For example

```
public @interface Foo {

    Config value();

}


public @interface Config {

    boolean ignoreUnknown() default false;
    int steps() default 2;
}
```

I would like to use @Foo (without specifying the value, so it should be some kind of optional) and I would also like to be able to write something like this:

```
@Foo (
    @Config(
        ignoreUnknown = true,
        steps = 10
    )
)
```

Is it possible to do something like this with annotations?

I don't want to do something like this

```
public @interface Foo {

   boolean ignoreUnknown() default false;
   int steps() default 2;
}
```

because I want to be able to distinguish if a property has been set or not (and not if it has the default value or not).

It's a little bit complicated to describe, but I'm working on a little Annotation Processor which generates Java code. However at runtime I would like to setup a default config that should be used for all @Foo, excepted those who have set own configuration with @Config.

so what I want is something like this:

```
public @interface Foo {

       Config value() default null;

 }
```

But as far as I know its not possible, right? Does anybody knows a workaround for such an optional attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error setting a default null value for an annotation's field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178104/error-setting-a-default-null-value-for-an-annotations-field)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, you can't use `null` for an annotation attribute value. However you can use an array type and provide an empty array.

```
public @interface Foo {
    Config[] value();  
}
...
@Foo(value = {})
```

or

```
public @interface Foo {
    Config[] value() default {};  
}
...
@Foo
```

Comment: Yes, but than I always have to write `@Foo(value = {})`  and in 90 % of usage I do not want to provide another Configuration, so I would like to have only `@Foo`

Comment: @sockeqwe It's as easy as setting a `default {}`.

Answer (score 6):

try that:

```
Config value() default @Config();
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Sotirios Delimanolis answer is correct, but I would like to explain on why this restriction even exists.

In Java, annotation attribute values cannot be `null` because the [JLS defines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) that annotation attributes must have a constant value ***known at compile-time***. Therefore, an annotation attribute can possibly be:

1. A constant expression that is known at compile-time (like `1`, `"Hello"`, `Month.JULY`, etc.)
2. An element value pair (afaik it is like other annotations `@Config`)
3. An array initializer (like `{1, 2, 3}`)

As you see, `null` [is not considered as a value known at compile-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1). Therefore you have this restriction. So it's not that `null` is somehow specifically excluded as an annotation value by language developers, it's just not considered to be known at compile time :)