# How to code optional default annotation value for Annotation TYPE

Tags: java, annotations

According to [error-setting-a-default-null-value-for-an-annotations-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178104/error-setting-a-default-null-value-for-an-annotations-field)

its not possible to affect null to an optional default value, here my case

having

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) 
public @interface SubView {
    Class EntityType();
    String[] Listing();
}
```

how to encode the default value for the optional SubView property?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SubTab {
    String name();
    String[] Fields() default {};
    SubView SubView() default ??? ; //this is optional how to code it?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

trial and error

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SubTab {
    String name();
    String[] Fields() default {};
    SubView SubView() default @SubView(Listing={}, EntityType=Object.class);
}
```