# How to handle nullable generics with Java interop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I have a Java class that is out of my control, defined as:

```java
public @interface ValueSource {
    String[] strings() default {}
}
```

I am trying to use this class from a Kotlin file I control, like so:

```java
class Thing {
    @ValueSource(string = ["non-null", null])
    fun performAction(value: String?) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error

> ```
> Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<String?> but Array<String> was expected.
> ```

I understand why the inferred type is `Array<String?>`, but why is the expected type not the same? Why is Kotlin interpreting the Java generic as `String!` rather than `String?`? And finally, is there a way to suppress the error?

Kotlin 1.2.61

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a Kotlin issue - this code isn't valid either, because Java simply doesn't allow `null` values in annotation parameters:

```
public class Thing {

    @ValueSource(strings = {"non-null", null}) // Error: Attribute value must be constant
    void performAction(String value) {
        // Do stuff
    }

}
```

See [this article](http://darkforge.blogspot.com/2008/03/java-annotation-parameters-cant-default.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1178104) for more discussion on this.