# Default null value for annotation fields in Java

Tags: java, annotations

I am creating a custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyFramework {

    public Integer index() default null; // Compiler complains here

}
```

The compiler  complains that `null` is not allowed. I do not want to make the index field primitive type `int` as it would not make sense. Is there a way to have a default `null` value for annotation fields?

The answer at [Error setting a default null value for an annotation's field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178104/error-setting-a-default-null-value-for-an-annotations-field) mention about `Class` type so the solutions work, but not for `Integer`, `Double` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `null` as a default (or non-default) value. Using `null` is expressly forbidden by the *Java Language Specification* (JLS). From [§9.6.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.2):

> **It is a compile-time error if the type of the element is not commensurate ([§9.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7)) with the default value specified.**

And from [§9.7.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1):

> **It is a compile-time error if the element type is not *commensurate* with the element value. An element type `T` is commensurate with an element value `V` if and only if one of the following is true**:
>
> - `T` is an array type `E[]`, and either:
>
>   - If `V` is a *ConditionalExpression* or an *Annotation*, then `V` is commensurate with `E`; or
>   - If `V` is an *ElementValueArrayInitializer*, then each element value that `V` contains is commensurate with `E`.
>
>     <sup>*An ElementValueArrayInitializer is similar to a normal array initializer (§10.6), except that an ElementValueArrayInitializer may syntactically contain annotations as well as expressions and nested initializers. However, nested initializers are not semantically legal in an ElementValueArrayInitializer because they are never commensurate with array-typed elements in annotation type declarations (nested array types not permitted).*</sup>
> - `T` is not an array type, and the type of `V` is assignment compatible (§5.2) with `T`, and:
>
>   - If `T` is a primitive type or `String`, then `V` is a constant expression (§15.28).
>   - If `T` is `Class` or an invocation of `Class` (§4.5), then `V` is a class literal (§15.8.2).
>   - If `T` is an enum type (§8.9), then `V` is an enum constant (§8.9.1).
>   - `V` is not `null`.
>
> <sup>*Note that if `T` is not an array type or an annotation type, the element value must be a ConditionalExpression (§15.25). The use of ConditionalExpression rather than a more general production like Expression is a syntactic trick to prevent assignment expressions as element values. Since an assignment expression is not a constant expression, it cannot be a commensurate element value for a primitive or `String`-typed element.*</sup>
>
> [...]

It's that last bullet point, "`V` is not `null`", that's the reason for your compilation error.

If you want a default value that means "not set" then use a non-null sentinel value. For instance, if a negative number is never a valid value then you can use any negative number (e.g. `-1`, `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, etc.) as a default value. For example:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyFramework {

  // note the "public" modifier is implicitly added
  Integer index() default Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```